# Transforming source word into target word

Tags: python

I need some help with my code. I need to convert one input word into another, changing one letter at a time. currently my program does this but very inefficiently and does not find the shortest route. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import re
def same(item, target):
  return len([c for (c, t) in zip(item, target) if c == t])

def build(pattern, words, seen, list):
  return [word for word in words
                 if re.search(pattern, word) and word not in seen.keys() and
                    word not in list]

def find(word, words, seen, target, path):
  list = []
  for i in range(len(word)):
    list += build(word[:i] + "." + word[i + 1:], words, seen, list)
  if len(list) == 0:
    return False
  list = sorted([(same(w, target), w) for w in list])
  for (match, item) in list:
    if match >= len(target) - 1:
      if match == len(target) - 1:
        path.append(item)
      return True
    seen[item] = True
  for (match, item) in list:
    path.append(item)
    if find(item, words, seen, target, path):
      return True
    path.pop()

fname = 'dictionary.txt'
file = open(fname)
lines = file.readlines()
while True:
  start = input("Enter start word:")
  words = []
  for line in lines:
    word = line.rstrip()
    if len(word) == len(start):
      words.append(word)
  target = input("Enter target word:")
  break

count = 0
path = [start]
seen = {start : True}
if find(start, words, seen, target, path):
  path.append(target)
  print(len(path) - 1, path)
else:
  print("No path found")
```

edit: Below is another failed attempt by me to fix this problem by trying a different approach. This time it does not seem to loop properly.

```
def find(start, words, target): # find function. Word = start word, words =

  start=list(start)
  target=list(target)

  print("Start word is ", start)
  print("Target word is ", target)


  letter = 0
  while start != target:
      if letter == len(target):
          letter = 0
          continue

      elif start[letter] == target[letter]:
          letter = letter + 1
          continue

      else:
          testword = list(start)
          testword[letter] = target[letter]
          testword = ''.join(testword)
          if testword in words:
              start[letter] = target[letter]
              letter = letter + 1
              print(start)
              continue
          else:
              letter = letter + 1
              continue

      letter = letter + 1
      continue




fname = "dictionary.txt"
file = open(fname) # Open the dictionary
lines = file.readlines() # Read each line from the dictionary and store it in lines
while True: # Until ended
  start = input("Enter start word:") # Take a word from the user
  words = [] # Inititialise Array 'words'
  for line in lines: # For each line in the dictionary
    word = line.rstrip() #strip all white space and characters from the end of a string
    if len(word) == len(start):
      words.append(word)

  if start not in words:
      print("Your start word is not valid")
      continue

  target = input("Enter target word:")
  if len(start) != len(target):
      print("Please choose two words of equal length")
      continue

  if target not in words:
      print("Your target word is not valid")
      continue


  break
```

edit: Here is the basic algorithm to the code. (Both variants are compatiable with my purpose).

```
-input start word
-input target word
- if len(start) = len(target)
       continue
       -check dictionary to see if target and start words are present
       - find what letters are different from the start to target word
       - change one different letter in the start word until start word 
        =target 
        word #after each letter change, output must be valid word in dictionary
The goal is to achieve this in the least amount of steps which is not achieved, the first section of code does this, I think but in a huge amount of steps I know could be far more efficient
```

Comment: Could you give an example of dictionary.txt, an input and expected output?

Comment: dictionary txt is a file containing the whole dictionary, the program asks for 2 inputs, both have to be the same length for the program to work and expected output is meant to be printing each step the program makes in its transition from the first user input to second. At every stage, the output must be a valid word in dictionary.txt

Comment: Is the conversion always possible using the dictionary?

Comment: The conversion will not always be possible. only one letter at a time can be changed to convert the first word into a new one it wont always work.

Comment: It would help if you briefly describe your algorithms in words, and add a few comments at key points in your code. That would make it a lot easier for people to check that your code is doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: Note that Jack asked for an **example**. This should be two specific words for the input and the expected output. The explanation you give helps us understand the general concept. A specific example will make the general concept much more clear, for us, and more importantly for you.

Comment: an example of the inputs would be "hide" and "seek" with the expected output being hide->side->site->sies->sees->seek

Comment: Looks like a breadth first search after constructing a reachable graph for each word should work.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @jack ive never used graphs before but atleast I know the foundation to the solution. :)

Comment: @user3012481 I've added an answer (a while back, but didn't think it worked well enough so deleted it, but it does the job so undeleted it) which shows using a graph library to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a breadth-first search that doesn't use any 3rd party modules. I don't guarantee that it finds the shortest solutions, but it appears to work. ;) It stops when it finds a solution, but due to the random order of sets each run of the program may find a different solution for a given start & target pair.

```
import re

# The file containing the dictionary
fname = '/usr/share/dict/words'

start, target = 'hide', 'seek'

wlen = len(start)
wrange = range(wlen)

words = set()
with open(fname) as f:
    for word in f:
        w = word.rstrip()
        # Grab words of the correct length that aren't proper nouns
        # and that don't contain non-alpha chars like apostrophe or hyphen
        if len(w) == wlen and w.islower() and w.isalpha():
            words.add(w)
print('word set size:', len(words))

# Build a regex to find words that differ from `word` by one char
def make_pattern(word):
    pat = '|'.join(['{}.{}'.format(word[:i], word[i+1:]) for i in wrange])
    return re.compile(pat)

# Find words that extend each chain of words in `seq`
def find(seq):
    result = []
    seen = set()
    for current in seq:
        pat = make_pattern(current[-1])
        matches = {w for w in words if pat.match(w)} - seen
        if target in matches:
            return current + (target,)
        result.extend(current + (w,) for w in matches)
        seen.update(matches)
        words.difference_update(matches)
    seq[:] = result

# Search for a solution
seq = [(start,)]
words.discard(start)
while True:
    solution = find(seq)
    if solution:
        print(solution)
        break
    size = len(seq)
    print(size)
    if size == 0:
        print('No solutions found')
        break
```

**typical output**

```
word set size: 2360
9
55
199
479
691
('hide', 'hire', 'here', 'herd', 'heed', 'seed', 'seek')
```

---

I ought to mention that all those word chains chew up a bit of RAM, I'll try to think of a more compact approach. But it shouldn't really be a problem on modern machines, unless you're working with really large words.

Comment: Thanks for your input, pretty close to exactly what I was looking for, cheers for the help aswell as the other contributors to this post :)

Answer (score 2):

Using a bit of preprocessing to group equal length words, you can use the `networkx` 3rd party library to build a graph, then use its `shortest_path` algorithm to retrieve it. Note that I've used the default dictionary available on most *nix systems and limited it to words of 5 characters or less.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import networkx as nx

# Group the words into equal length so we only compare within words of equal length
with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as fin:
    words = defaultdict(set)
    for word in (line.strip() for line in fin if line.islower() and len(line) <= 6):
        words[len(word)].add(word)

graph = nx.Graph()
for k, g in words.items():
    while g:
        word = g.pop()
        matches = {w for w in g if sum(c1 != c2 for c1, c2 in zip(word, w)) == 1}
        graph.add_edges_from((word, match) for match in matches)
```

Then, get the shortest route, eg:

```
In [1]: ' -> '.join(nx.shortest_path(graph, 'hide', 'seek'))
Out[1]: 'hide -> hire -> here -> herd -> heed -> seed -> seek'

In [2]: ' -> '.join(nx.shortest_path(graph, 'cat', 'dog'))
Out[2]: 'cat -> cot -> cog -> dog'
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, unfortunately I cannot use 3rd party libraries due to limitations in my end

Comment: @user3012481 you can imagine a graph as a `dict` of word->{set of words one letter different} and then write your own fairly simple traveral algorithm

Comment: awesome thanks for the input, this is all new to me but ill try my best thanks for the help its much appreciated